# SVG Patterned Image to behave like "background-size:cover"

Tags: html, css, svg

I am looking for a way to make a background image, set using a pattern, to behave like the regular css attribute `background-size` when set to `cover`. The pen below shows that the main image stretches to fit the container which results in the image being distored. I want to replicate how 'background-image:cover` works but for an SVG pattern. The section below gives you some idea of the context in which this will be used. Is there a way to achieve this? Is there a better way to mark this up?

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:600px">
 <svg width="100%" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="transparent">
   <defs>
    <pattern id="bg" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0">
      <image href="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?grayscale" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
    </pattern>
   </defs>
   <clipPath id="myClip">
    <polygon points="0,0, 0,100, 100,80, 100, 0"></polygon>
   </clipPath>
   <polygon id="poly" points="0,0 0,100, 100,100, 100, 0" mask="url(#myClip)"></polygon>
   <use clip-path="url(#myClip)" xlink:href="#poly" fill="url(#bg)"></use>
  </svg>
</div>

<div style="background-color:lightblue;height:600px;padding:30px;margin-top:-150px">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;padding:50px;padding-top:150px;box-sizing:border-box">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Ut nec arcu porta, vestibulum lorem et, ullamcorper nulla. Nam quis mollis odio. Aliquam neque nibh, imperdiet eu ante ut, tincidunt egestas elit. Duis nulla nulla, malesuada vel gravida id, aliquam ac odio. Sed id ex viverra, cursus velit id, iaculis nibh. Ut non porta augue, at sodales felis. Nunc lobortis euismod diam ut fringilla. Quisque molestie, nisl nec malesuada accumsan, massa tortor laoreet tellus, vitae bibendum nulla nisl non metus. Morbi congue felis sed felis semper molestie. Mauris quis lectus aliquam, suscipit felis ut, luctus dui. Etiam aliquam at ipsum at tempor. Integer hendrerit, purus vel tristique aliquam, ipsum orci ultrices felis, a suscipit ligula velit nec sem. Ut at laoreet nulla, at faucibus nulla.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div style="float:right;height:100%;width:50%;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?grayscale)">
  </div>
</div>
```

For an added bonus point, is it possible to make this a fixed background (i.e. `like background-attachment:fixed`)

Comment: Put your SVG as background with no `width` or `height` and use `background-size:cover`. See doc here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds#Source_No_dimensions_or_intrinsic_ratio_2

Comment: Can you provide a working example? Unsure on which element the bg should be applied to. The issue I have here is that I need to clip the background so the elements behind are visible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/btuwmasd/ and you can clip your div using the `clip` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Comment: On a side note, you should try to separate your CSS from your HTML. Inline CSS isn't scalable and is a pain to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but your example doesn't make use of clip - just an svg used as a background which isn't the issue here. If I want to use an image as a background and clip that rather than a colour, I still end up with the same issue. Rather than explicitly define the SVG within my HTML I've put it in the background property.

Comment: You titled your question SVG Background Image to behave like “background-size:cover” and that's what this does. Your post doesn't explain much beyond that so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. If you want examples of CSS clip, here are a few: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: I've added some clarification. Hopefully, that is enough to convey what I want to achieve. If you look at the snippet in the post, you will see that the top image is stretched. I want this image in this area to behave like `background-size:cover` does for a regular background image so that the image does not stretch (and this become distorted)

Comment: I've also amended the title.

Comment: @Zakalwe The big image should fit to window but without stretching?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Yes. So it bhanves like "background-size:cover" would for a regular background image.

Comment: @Zakalwe the width is 100% and the height is 600px how it's possible to not stretch. You should set height to % as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to overcomplicate a simple task that can be done using clip-path

```css
.header {
  height:400px;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% calc(100% - 150px),0 100%); /* update the calc(100% - 150px) to control the curve */
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?grayscale) center/cover fixed;
}
```

```html
<div  class="header"></div>
<div style="background-color:lightblue;height:600px;padding:30px;margin-top:-150px">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;padding:50px;padding-top:150px;box-sizing:border-box">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Ut nec arcu porta, vestibulum lorem et, ullamcorper nulla. Nam quis mollis odio. Aliquam neque nibh, imperdiet eu ante ut, tincidunt egestas elit. Duis nulla nulla, malesuada vel gravida id, aliquam ac odio. Sed id ex viverra, cursus velit id, iaculis nibh. Ut non porta augue, at sodales felis. Nunc lobortis euismod diam ut fringilla. Quisque molestie, nisl nec malesuada accumsan, massa tortor laoreet tellus, vitae bibendum nulla nisl non metus. Morbi congue felis sed felis semper molestie. Mauris quis lectus aliquam, suscipit felis ut, luctus dui. Etiam aliquam at ipsum at tempor. Integer hendrerit, purus vel tristique aliquam, ipsum orci ultrices felis, a suscipit ligula velit nec sem. Ut at laoreet nulla, at faucibus nulla.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div style="float:right;height:100%;width:50%;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?grayscale)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. I was completely overthinking this. Thanks so much.